# React hook, wired issue when use useState, while if use setState work perfectly, how to solve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

dear community, I am facing a wired issue, and I don't know how to summary my situation in the question title, so I wonder if the question title is accurate enough.

I was trying to convert a class component to a hook component.

The class version code like this

```
async componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch, itemId } = this.props;
        try {
            if (itemId) {
                await dispatch({
                    type: 'assignment/fetchSubmissionsByAssignment', //here to fetch submissions in props
                    payload: {
                        id: itemId
                    }
                });
            }
            const { submissions } = this.props;
            this.setState({
                studentSubmissions: submissions,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            throw error.message;
        }
    }

render() {
        const { studentSubmissions } = this.state;
        return (
            <Table dataSource={studentSubmissions} />
        )
    }

export default SubmissionsDetail;
```

and in hook, it look like this

```
    const [studentSubmissions, setStudentSubmissions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchSubmissions() {
            const { dispatch, itemId } = props;
            try {
                if (itemId) {
                    await dispatch({
                        type: 'assignment/fetchSubmissionsByAssignment',
                        payload: {
                            id: itemId
                        }
                    });
                }
                const { submissions } = props;
                setStudentSubmissions(submissions)
            } catch (error) {
                throw error.message;
            }
        };
        fetchSubmissions()
    }, []);

return (
            <Table dataSource={studentSubmissions} />
        )

export default SubmissionsDetail;
```

I omitted some code for better reading, like connect to redux store or others.
and the component is import in the parent file like this

```
import SubmissionsDetail from './SubmissionsDetail'

{assignmentIds.map((itemId) => {
    <SubmissionsDetail itemId={itemId}/>
})}
```

it work perfect in class component, the expected result should return tables like this
[image]

However, when I change to use hook, the result return like this
[image]
or sometimes all data in tables become submissions3

I try to `console.log(submissions)` inside the `try{...}` block, when in class, the result is [image]

which is correct, there have two assignments, the one have 4 submissions, another one have zero submission.
But the output in hook is different, the result is like this
[image]

either both have 4 submissions, either both have zero. That means one obj affect all other obj.

It seems like if useState change, it would influence other objs, that make me really confused. I think in the map method, each item is independent, right? If so, and how to explain why it work perfectly in class setState, but failed in hook useState?

I hope my question is clear enough, If you know how to describe my question in short, plz let me know, I would update the title, to help locate experts to answer.

Please don't hesitate to share your opinions, I really appreciate and need your help, many thanks!

Comment: Can you console.log `submissions` inside the `try{...}` block, and tell us if it's different inside the class vs functional compoenent?

Comment: @MichaelHoobler Hi, I just add it in the description, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: You are probably going to want to rework the way you store the `submission` inside of the redux store if you really want to use the Hook Component. It seems like right now, submissions is just an array that gets overwritten whenever a new API call is made, and for some reason, the Class Component doesn't update (and it's suppose to update).

Sorry it's hard to make suggestions, your setup looks very different than the Redux environments I used. But here's how I would store the submissions:

```
// no submissions loaded
submissions: {} 

// loading new submission into a state
state: {
  ...state,
  sessions: {
    ...state.session,
    [itemId]: data
  }
}

// Setting the state inside the component
setStudentSubmissions(props.submissions[itemId])
```

And I think you will want to change

```
yield put({
  type: 'getSubmissions',
  payload: response.data.collections 
});
```

to something like

```
yield put({
  type: 'getSubmissions',
  payload: {
    data: response.data.collections,
    itemId: id
});
```

If you want to try a "hack" you can maybe get a `useMemo` to avoid updating? But again, you're doing something React is not suppose to do and this might not work:

```
// remove the useEffect and useState, and import useMemo
const studentSubmissions = useMemo(async () => {
  try {
    if (itemId) {
      await dispatch({
        type: "assignment/fetchSubmissionsByAssignment", //here to fetch submissions in props
        payload: {
          id: itemId,
        },
      });
      return this.props.submissions;
    }
    return this.props.submissions;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error.message;
  }
}, []);

return (
  <Table dataSource={studentSubmissions} />
)

export default SubmissionsDetail;
```

Comment: Yes, it change at all, I just add it in the description, in class, it return different result base on different itemId, but in hook, it return the same result

Comment: @RH-st Is `submissions` coming from Redux? Can you show me how `submissions` is getting it's values?

Comment: Yes, it come from Redux, in the model, it fetch data like this `*fetchSubmissionsByAssignment({ payload }, { call, put }) {
   const { id } = payload;
   const response = yield call(getSubmissionsByAssignment, id);
   if (response.status === 200) {
    yield put({
     type: 'getSubmissions',
     payload: response.data.collections
    });
   }
  }`
and then `reducers: {
  getSubmissions(state, { payload }) {
   return {
    ...state,
    submissions: payload
   };
  }`

Comment: `useMemo` doesn't work, but your suggestions about how to store submissions are really useful! Just to mention, it doesn't need to setting the state inside the component `setStudentSubmissions(props.submissions[itemId])` I try it, but eventually the result still get fail, same issue, but I change to pass props value directly like`<Table dataSource={props.submissions[itemId} />` it work perfectly! I guess the reason why setState not work is already well explained by @Linda Paiste answer. Again, thanks for your patient, your effect, your professionalism, many thanks for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use a local component state in either the class or the function component versions.  All that the local state is doing is copying the value of `this.props.submissions` which came from Redux.  [There's a whole section in the React docs about why copying props to state is bad](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html).  To summarize, it's bad because you get stale, outdated values.

Ironically, those stale values were allowing it to "work" before by covering up problems in your reducer.  Your reducer is resetting the value of `state.submissions` every time you change the `itemId`, but your components are holding on to an old value (which I suspect is actually the value for the previous component? `componentDidMount` will not reflect a change in props).

You want your components to select a current value from Redux based on their `itemId`, so your reducer needs to store the submissions for every `itemId` separately.  @Michael Hoobler's answer is correct in how to do this.

There's no problem if you want to keep using redux-saga and keep using `connect` but I wanted to give you a complete code so I am doing it my way which is with redux-toolkit, thunks, and react-redux hooks.  The component code becomes very simple.

Component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { fetchSubmissionsByAssignment } from "../store/slice";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "../store";

const SubmissionsDetail = ({ itemId }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const submissions = useSelector(
    (state) => state.assignment.submissionsByItem[itemId]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSubmissionsByAssignment(itemId));
  }, [dispatch, itemId]);

  return submissions === undefined ? (
    <div>Loading</div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <div>Assignment {itemId}</div>
      <div>Submissions {submissions.length}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubmissionsDetail;
```

Actions / Reducer:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const fetchSubmissionsByAssignment = createAsyncThunk(
  "assignment/fetchSubmissionsByAssignment",
  async (id) => {
    const response = await getSubmissionsByAssignment(id);
    // can you handle this in getSubmissionsByAssignment instead?
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error("invalid response");
    }
    return {
      itemId: id,
      submissions: response.data.collections
    };
  }
);

const initialState = { 
  submissionsByItem: {}
};

export default createReducer(initialState, (builder) =>
  builder.addCase(fetchSubmissionsByAssignment.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    const { itemId, submissions } = action.payload;
    state.submissionsByItem[itemId] = submissions;
  })
  // could also respond to pending and rejected actions
);
```

Comment: I hate why I can only accept one answer, I really benefit a lot from your answer, let me deepen my understanding of local component state in both class and functional component, the framework I use currently doesn't use thunk, but I can totally understand the elegant code you write. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you have an object as state, and want to merge a key to the previous state - do it like this

```js
const [myState, setMyState] = useState({key1: 'a', key2: 'b'});

setMyState(prev => {...prev, key2: 'c'});
```

the setter of the state hook accepts a callback that must return new state, and this callback recieves the previous state as a parameter.

Comment: Actually I want the current state won't affect previous state, it seems in class, I don't need to worry about it, but in hook, if current state change, it will affect previous render

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not include large part of the codes, and I assume everything works in class component (including your actions and reducers). I'm just making a guess that it may be due to the omission of `key`.

```
{assignmentIds.map((itemId) => {
    <SubmissionsDetail itemId={itemId} key={itemId} />
})}
```

**OR** it can be due to the other parts of our codes which were omitted.